# How sort List of Maps in Grrovy

Tags: groovy

I am new to groovy. Here is my code. I have a list of maps in groovy, like:

```
list = [[query:"insert into table", order:5],
        [query:"insert into table", order:1],
        [query:"insert into table", order:2]]
```

I am trying like below

```
list.sort({ob1,ob2 -> ob1.order <=> ob2.order})
```

I want to sort based on order.

Comment: `list.sort{it.order}` should be enough

Comment: `sort` returns a sorted copy; otherwise please state in your question, what is working? That code looks ok at first glance and should work, but there is clearly something wrong or else you would not have asked that question.